# Undelete answer deleted by moderator

Tags: support, answers, moderators

My [answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113973/could-a-recipe-achieve-the-force-of-halachah) here deleted by mod. I edited it so I think it valid now, but I can't undelete. what to do now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, a good way to notify the mods that a mod-only action is needed is to raise a flag.